# Application Health-Check Monitoring Tool

Tags: health

I am looking for an open source application health-check monitoring tool that could monitor application health-checks of a heterogeneous micro-service system with Java (Spring Boot health-check actuator endpoint) and .NET (ASP.NET HealthChecks) and some more applications not belonging to these two categories (but that can implement some similar health-check API).
The tool should be able to show:

- The current health status of the whole system (composed of tens of micro-services)
- Enable dive-in into specific application and its health sub-components and show info about the issue as name value pairs (as in SpringBoot/ASP.NET health-check APIs and other similar health-check APIs)
- Enable historical view for the whole system, as well as singe application
- Hopefully hierarchical decomposition of the system into sub-systems (each composed of several micro-services)

That would be a tool for health-check monitoring analog to what Prometheus and Grafana are for metrics, of what is ELK stack for event/log monitoring. Meaning a tool (or tools) should:

- Collect health checks from applications, supporting different formats like Spring Boot actuator health check and ASP.NET HealthChecks at least
- Store health-checks in its database
- Present full system, hopefully subsystems and application health check, current and historical

However, my search for such a tool is a failure, any suggestions on this topic?

Comment: The tag "health" is wrong, it is for medical health (e.g. of humans) only not for software monitoring. When it comes to software I would call it monitoring of the service state.